# What is the Right Syntax When Using .notnull() in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

I want to use `.notnull()` on several columns of a dataframe to eliminate the rows which contain "NaN" values.

Let say I have the following `df`:

```
  A   B   C
0 1   1   1
1 1   NaN 1
2 1   NaN NaN
3 NaN 1   1
```

I tried to use this syntax but it does not work? do you know what I am doing wrong?

```
df[[df.A.notnull()],[df.B.notnull()],[df.C.notnull()]]
```

I get this Error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

What should I do to get the following output?

```
  A   B   C
0 1   1   1
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can just do `df.dropna(subset=['A', 'B', 'C'])`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can first select subset of columns by `df[['A','B','C']]`, then apply [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) and specify if [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) values in mask are `True`:

```
print (df[['A','B','C']].notnull())
       A      B      C
0   True   True   True
1   True  False   True
2   True  False  False
3  False   True   True

print (df[['A','B','C']].notnull().all(1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

print (df[df[['A','B','C']].notnull().all(1)])
     A    B    C
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Another solution is from [`Ayhan`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702332/what-is-the-right-syntax-when-using-notnull-in-pandas#comment64782445_38702332) comment with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
print (df.dropna(subset=['A', 'B', 'C']))
     A    B    C
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

what is same as:

```
print (df.dropna(subset=['A', 'B', 'C'], how='any'))
```

and means drop all rows, where is at least one `NaN` value.

Comment: Thanks that make sense... what about the `.all()` what does that do? and how it is different from `.any()`?

Comment: `all` means check if all values are True and `any` means check if at least one value is True. And if use `all(1)` or `any(1)` it means check rows, because it is same as `all(axis=1)` or `any(axis=1)`

Comment: Your are awesome! Thanks a lot my friend

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day!

Answer (score 2):

You can apply multiple conditions by combining them with the `&` operator (this works not only for the `notnull()` function).

```
df[(df.A.notnull() & df.B.notnull() & df.C.notnull())]
     A    B    C
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Alternatively, you can just drop all columns which contain `NaN`. The original DataFrame is not modified, instead a copy is returned.

`df.dropna()`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```py
df.dropna()
```